# Looking for a way to use multithreading on selenium

Tags: python, multithreading, selenium

I have a project that would involve multithreading on selenium on python, where every chrome thread will have a different IP addresses of the same website. I have found that selenium itself is not scaleable. Many other stackoverflow articles say that selenium can not handle multithread and does do not offer a solution.

What are the ways to get around this? If not, what are some alternatives?